# How not to hash part of user data in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, encryption

In my cake app user needs to submit mobile number with the registration form, I see that mobile number is automatically encrypted to some other number, how do I not encrypt part of user data ? especially the 10 digit mobile number ?

Comment: Encrypted? Can you show an example (what number you put in the form, and what was saved in the database)? Also, what data type is the field in the database (varchar, int...)?

Comment: juhana it is int and I all that is stored is different numbers of length 10

Comment: for example, this is stored 2147483647 in the database

Comment: So that number is stored correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the database field is of type int I'm guessing the issue arises when you try to save phone numbers that are not strictly integers, i.e. +123456, 123 456 789, 00123 456, 123-456-789 etc. You must use a `varchar` field to store phone numbers that include spaces, hyphens, pluses or start with a zero.

Comment: Juhana it is working when I declare it as varchar , but I always entered an integer without spaces and hyphens and + signs, so what do you think is converting the data into another format ?

Comment: Really, it's impossible to say without seeing *both* what you try to input and what it turns into. Like this: "I try to put in 123 and it converts into 456". It's likely that the upper limit of the int was met and it overflowed.